# Are ring signatures complicated to implement? Would adding them later end up in massively rewriting code?

Tags: cryptography, blockchain, digital-signature, ecdsa

I'm currently involved in the development of a blockchain voting application using very standard public/private key ECDSA. Are ring signatures something that I can add later or would I end up needing to massively rewrite a-lot of code?

Comment: seems somewhat off-topic, it depends on what you want to do with them as well as how you implement the rest of your code